# How to cover 100% Sonarqube code coverage on Java bean class with @Getter @Builder Lombok annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, sonarqube, lombok

I am calling a third party REST endpoint.

**Request sample**

```
{
     "body": {
        "accountNumber": "12345"
     },
     "header": {
        "username": "someusername",
        "password": "somepassword"
     }
}
```

I have created 3 bean classes

**MyRequest.java**

```
@Builder
@JsonDeserialize(builder =  MyRequest.MyRequestBuilder.class)
public class MyRequest {
    @JsonProperty("header")
    private MyHeader header;
    @JsonProperty("body")
    private MyBody body;
}
```

**MyBody.java**

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class MyBody {
    private String accountNumber;
}
```

**MyHeader.java**

```
@Getter
@Builder
public class MyHeader {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

I'm creating request object using

```
MyBody body = MyBody.builder().accountNumber("12345").build();
MyHeader header = MyHeader.builder().username("someusername").password("somepassword").build();

MyRequest request = MyRequest.builder().body(body).header(header).build();
```

Everything is working as expected. The code coverage for MyRequest.java is 100% but my MyBody.java and MyHeader.java is not.
For all the fields I get the error message "Not covered by tests".

Normally I add @Getter and @Setter for Response objects. For request, I just add @Builder annotation.
In this case, if I remove @Getter from MyBody and MyHeader, the third party REST endpoint is getting null values.
It looks like @Getter is invoked when setting the objects to MyRequest.java. But for some reason it is not covered by my test cases.

How to make this work without @Getter or is there a way to cover all the fields (accountNumber, username and password) with @Getter annotation? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Create a lombok.config and add the following attribute to it.

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

For Maven projects, a file named lombok.config at project’s basedir is the right spot, but other ways/locations may apply, see https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration

Comment: This will not be approved by my team. Looking for some other solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to instruct Jackson somehow which data should be included during serialization. The default mechanism is to use getters for that purpose.

Replace @Getter with @JsonProperty to get 100% code coverage.

```
@Builder
public class MyBody {
    @JsonProperty
    private String accountNumber;
}
```

This is not my answer. I got this answer from my other post
[Why 3rd party REST API's gets null values for request fields when removing @Getter Lombok annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74660036/why-3rd-party-rest-apis-gets-null-values-for-request-fields-when-removing-gett)

Thanks @Alexander Ivanchenko